# Why am I getting this strange output on this simple C program?

Tags: c

I am working on a personal project where one part of it deals with counting squares and cubes under a certain bound (in this case 10,000). So, I wrote a simple C program I thought would work to verify my results. Here is the little program I put together to see all of the cubes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main() {

      double i;
      int cubes = 0;

      for (i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {

        if ( i == cbrt(i) * cbrt(i) * cbrt(i) ) {

             printf("%f --- %f\n",i, cbrt(i));
             cubes++;
         }
       }

     printf("%i\n", cubes);

     return 0;
}
```

I got the (incorrect) output : 24. If you want to look at this see the problem look at numbers 15 and 20 on the output. Why I am getting the wrong answer (the correct answer is 21) is an entirely different matter. My question arose when I was messing around with my code to try and fix this and I temporarily changed it to this:

```
int main() {

    double i;
    int cubes = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {

        double temp = (cbrt(i) * cbrt(i) * cbrt(i));

        if ( i == temp ) {

            printf("%f -> %f\n", i, temp);
            cubes++;
        }
     }

   printf("%i\n", cubes);

   return 0;
}
```

Now, the program is printing every number between 1 and 9999. So, am I missing something ridiculously easy or what is going on? All I did was instead of having `cbrt(i)*cbrt(i)*cbrt(i)` in the if conditional I set a double variable equal to result and placed that in the conditional. Why is my program doing this?

I am not sure why this got down voted. I feel like this is a legitimate question. Sorry S.O. community...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to find numbers with whole-number cube roots?

Comment: First impression - You're checking floating point numbers (`double`) for equality, that's just looking for problem. Why don't You use simple `int` instead? or `uint64_t`, or whatever.

Comment: assuming i is an int and temp is a double you won't often achieve equality due to the double's internal rounding.

Comment: @Duck: `i` is a double.  It says so at the top of the code.

Comment: @user3270407 There are infinite numbers even between 0.0 and 1.0. A double is normally 64 bits big, and can therefore only store a finite amount of numbers. So calculations done with floating point numbers on a computer are approximations. It would also help if you explain why the number 24 is incorrect and 21 is correct.

Comment: Yikes, you are right.

Comment: (cube root of X) cubed is equal to X is it not?

Comment: You should find cube root of 10000, loop from 0 the floor of that value cubing all numbers to find perfect cubes

Comment: @AndrewMedico I am trying to find the number of perfect cubes under 10,000. However, I was more concerned with why the one small change threw off the program so drastically.

Comment: @dboals Mathematically yes "(cube root of X) cubed is equal to X", but the finite precision of a `double` prevents an exact solution.

Comment: @chux That part I know.  I guess I miss understood what his problem was.  I thought he was saying that he had weird behavior in both version of the routine.  I was implying that the retults on the second version were correct. My bad.

Comment: BTW, for me `clang` generates code that results in 3318 from both codes. I still think the behaviour `the program is printing every number between 1 and 9999` can only be the result of some optimization by the compiler.

Comment: @user3270407 Hope you got all your questions answered.

Comment: Yes I certainly did. Thank you for all of your help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double cbrt(double x)` returns the closest representable cubic root of `x`.

The inexactness of the result, then cubed, may not exactly equal 'x' again.

---

Why 2nd program differs:

C is not obliged to perform `double` math *only* to `double` precision.  It may use wider (`long double`).  Depending on many things, the 2nd code appears to have done more in `long double` than the first.  With the extra precision, its easy to see that the results, rounded to `double` appear exact.

> C11dr §5.2.4.2.2 9 Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating constants are **evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type**.

---

Why a typical program run (of either code) produces a result of about 3333.

Consider the `double` numbers from 2 to 4 and 8 to 64.  `double` numbers are logarithmically distributed.  There are as many different `double` from 2 to 4 as 8 to 16 as 16 to 32 as 32 to 64.

So now all 3 sets from 8 to 64 have a cube root of *some* answer in the 1 set of 2 to 4.  Now if we cube the numbers 2 to 4, we get answers in the range 8 to 64.  1 set of numbers mapping into 3 sets.  The round trip is not exact.  See [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  IOW: On average, 3 numbers in the range 8 to 64 have the *same* cubic root.  Then the cube of that root will be 1 of the 3 original.

---

To find the count of the perfect integer cubes 0 to N

```
unsigned Perfect_Cube_Count(unsigned n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  unsigned i;
  // overflow not possible
  for (i = 0; i*i < n/i; i++);
  return i;
}
```

Or

```
// valid for 0 <= x <= something_well_over_1e9
double Perfect_Cube_Count_d(double x) {
  double y = cbrt(x);
  return floor(y) + 1;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't explain to me the ` the program is printing every number between 1 and 9999` behaviour.

Comment: OP prints a count at end of the loop, it would be hard to miss the result...

Comment: @Buella Gábor True .... Hmmmm.  When I run the 2 programs I get 3321 both times.  3321 is expected as it is about 1/3 of 9999 which follows the pigeon hole augment above.  I now suspect a weak `cbrt(double x)` coding or some interesting setting of rounding.

Comment: Yes, I get the 3318 with both programs, but getting 9999 as count is weird - and this is the OP's question about.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about using `floor` . BTW that gives wrong results, for example `Perfect_Cubed(1)` and `Perfect_Cubed(2)` both result in 2. Just treat `x == 1` separately, and also, don't add one to the floored number. Ah, I should stop with this now...

Comment: @Buella Gábor Both should report 2 as I am count from 0 and 0 and 1 are perfect cubes.  But you are correct - time to go.  Thank for the feedback +1

Comment: I tried also with larger numbers, still doesn't seem reliable to me...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want, as Andrew guessed, whole-number cube roots. Float math is quite tricky because of rounding errors. Generally you cannot rely on equality but must compare with an error margin.

To solve your problem though I'd *construct* the 21 cubes beforehand and then iterate over integers, comparing against the pre-constructed cubes. Or is that cheating? ;-)

In Samuel Becket's novel Watt there is a chapter about a Scottish "Math genius" who could in his head compute all integer third roots of integer cubes up to 10000 or so, too!

Answer (score 1):

My uess, is your compiler does an optimization in the second case, eli inating cbrt calls. It just says the result of cbrt is strictly defined by the standard, so it might as well be always thte case that (i == temp)

You can twak this by some command line arguments, and force it to do exactly what is written in the code. As I recall, this should thhe default thing to do for C compilers regarding float arthimetic, but your compiler may think it is smarter than you or something.

**EDIT**

And yes, this code has nothing to do with finding perfect cubes...

**EDIT**
Totally not an answer to the question, but as a quick exercise, this I wrote this:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <limits.h>

 static unsigned long count_cubes(unsigned long max_n)
 {
     unsigned long n = 1;
     while (n*n*n <= max_n) {
         ++n;
     }
     return n-1;
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     unsigned long max_n;
     char *p;

     if (argc < 2) {
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }
     max_n = strtoul(argv[1], &p, 10);
     if (max_n < 1 || max_n == ULONG_MAX) {
         return EXIT_FAILURE;

     }
     printf("%lu\n", count_cubes(max_n));
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Note: no need for floating point arithmetic

**EDIT**

Sorry, I really got into this...

This one can be a bit faster:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include <math.h>

 static unsigned long count_cubes(unsigned long max_n)
 {
     unsigned long n;
     if (max_n < 256) {
         n = 1;
     }
     else {
         n = cbrtl(max_n) - 1;
     }
     while (n*n*n <= max_n) {
         ++n;
     }
     return n-1;
 }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     unsigned long max_n;
     char *p;

     if (argc < 2) {
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }
     max_n = strtoul(argv[1], &p, 10);
     if (max_n < 1 || max_n == ULONG_MAX) {
         return EXIT_FAILURE;

     }
     printf("%lu\n", count_cubes(max_n));
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

**EDIT** ( last time, I promise... )

To show an explanation of my little loop above, starting at `cbrt(max_n)-1`, I tried the one suggested by @chux , here are some results with slightly larger numbers:

`PerfectCubes(18446724184312856125) == 2642246`

which is fine but also

`PerfectCubes(18446724184312856125-10) == 2642246`

which is totally not fine, since `18446724184312856125 == 2642245^3` , meaning there are 2642245 perfect cubes <= 18446724184312856125-10 .

This also results from inaccuracies in floating point representation. You can try it for yourself, if your computer is somewhat similar to mine:

```
     printf("%f\n", cbrt( 2642245UL * 2642245UL * 2642245UL));
     /* prints 2642245.000000 */
     printf("%f\n", cbrt( 2642245UL * 2642245UL * 2642245UL - 10UL));
     /* prints 2642245.000000 */
```

These two numbers clearly don't have the same cubic root, yet `cbrt` returns the same results. In this case, `floor` doesn't help either. Anyways, one always needs to be very careful using floating point arithmetics. And now I really should go to sleep.